# Getting __protected_call__ in inspect function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using `inspect.stack()[1].function` to fetch the name of the function but I'm getting the value `__protected_call_`.

The function is decorated as a Celery task.

How to get the actual func name?

Comment: Will `inspect.stack()[0].function` do the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inspect.stack()[0].function` returns the actual function throwing the error.